# Parenthesis in define macros

Tags: c, macros

When is it is **necessary** to put the whole (right) expression of a define macro in parenthesis?

If I do something like

```
#define SUM(x, y) ((x)+(y))
```

I have to put the right expression into parenthesis, because "+" has a low precedence in C (and it wouldn't work if I would use it in the following context `SUM(x, y) * 5U`)

Are these parenthesis still required if I use an operator of the highest precedence e.g.

```
#define F foo()
```

or even

```
#define ACCESS(x, y) (x)->(y)
```

Does an expression exist that  that would break the actual meaning as it would do for the `SUM()` example?)

For the precedence rules  I used http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: I don't know about *necessary*, but I'd still call it good practice. What if someone (say) adds a correction factor to the `F` macro to (whatever) normalize the output of `foo`, and forgets to add the parenthesis? You'll be spending a lot of time trying to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Also worth noting that the table of precedence you reference *isn't actually the language standard*, but is rather an easier-to-use representation of more complicated rules in the standard. I'm no C expert or language lawyer, but those rules might change things.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good practice to use parenthesis to avoid some big blunders. Currently you might think that your operator is having high precedence but suppose you're making the header file of your code and give it to your friend who uses macro from that file with the function having even higher precedence so at that time it will be a great pain to debug the code. You can save this time as a programmer by putting parenthesis.

Comment: My question was when it is *necessary* to put parenthesis around a macro. Of course, if the operator has a low precedence e.g. "+" then parentheses are always required (like in the SUM example). But what about expressions with high precedence like "->", "++", "[]", "." ?

Comment: I think I found a good example which shows why "It's a good practice to use parenthesis to avoid some big blunders." is not always right! Imagine you have a `#define foo()` and `foo` is defined as `do{  } while(0)` then this won't compile anymore!

Answer (score -1):

Some programmers using simple #defines will write

```
#define ZERO (0)
```

which is of no use other than complicating things.

Actually the macro is wysiwyg so with that in mind you can decide what parentheses are needed:

```
SUM(3,4) => ((3)+(4))    // parentheses around 3 and 4 are not necessary

RATIO(3+4,4+5) => ((3+4)/(4+5))    // probably necessary here due to operator precedence
```

Its not rocket science to figure this out, it's actually quite straightforward.

Comment: I think this does not answer my question, you just explained how macros are evaluated in C.

Comment: Yes that is what i just did. Did you think parentheses in macros are evaluated differently than in other C statements.